# Single Key Multiple Accounts to Map

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary, hashmap

My map is declared as `private Map accountByReport;`
I am using the below loop to check if the `reportID` is in the map or not before adding the corresponding Department Account to the key. Is my loop correct and what should the type declaration be in this instance and how can I catch exceptions?

```
 for(Entity entity : entities) {
  if(accountsByReport.containsKey(entity.getReportID())) {
      ((List<String>)accountsByReport.get(entity.getReportID())).add(entity.getDepAccount());
  } else {
      accountsByReport.put(entity.getReportID(), new ArrayList<String>().add(entity.getDepAccount()));
  }
}
```

Comment: how should I add type arguments to the Map declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are adding a boolean (the return ok `.add()`) to the map in the else.
I would use this way:

```
  for(Entity entity : entities) {
        if(accountsByReport.containsKey(entity.getReportID())) {
            ((List<String>)accountsByReport.get(entity.getReportID())).add(entity.getDepAccount());
        } else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(entity.getDepAccount());
            accountsByReport.put(entity.getReportID(), list);
        }
    }
```

You didn't paste the Map definition, but you should use typed parameters - i.e. `Map<String, List<String>> accountsByReport = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();` so you don't need to do casting after `.get`

In fact you pasted it. 
Use: `private Map<String, List> accountByReport;`

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct so far, but your `Map` should declare with type

The map should be declared based on the type of reportID,

```
//if String
private Map<String, List<String>> accountByReport;
//if int
private Map<Integer, List<String>> accountByReport;
//so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is essentially correct. The only improvements you can make is to do a single get and store the result rather than doing both a contains and a get. You should also use generics so you don't need the cast..

```
   List<String> list = accountsByReport.get(entity.getReportID())

        if(list != null) {
            list.add(entity.getDepAccount());
        } else {
            accountsByReport.put(entity.getReportID(), new ArrayList<String>().add(entity.getDepAccount()));
        }
```